# How to make keystroke auto completion in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on making a function which does auto completion based on keystrokes.
Like, in google.com when I hit 'a' in search bar, it shows the related search words such as amazon, amazon prime, airbnb...
I am trying make this function using Python and my CSV file based on detecting keystrokes.
There are some words in the CSV file such as Behavior, Building, Chemistry, History, Manufacturing, Mathematics.
The structure of my code consists of

```
while # infinitely looping in order to keep detecting keystrokes
    for word in data 
        for char in range(numOfKeyStrokes)
```

The problem is, when I hit 'c', it is supposed to print out chemistry and it works great.
But when I hit 'h' after I already hit 'c', there is no response.
I want to make this printing out "chemistry" again.
I think when I hit 'h', the compiler doesn't go into "for word in data" statement but I don't know why.
There are some junk print outs in order to detect where the problem is.
Here is my code. Can someone help my problem?

```python
import keyboard
import csv
import time

global numOfKeyStrokes  #In order to compare each elemtn's letter one by one with keystroke
numOfKeyStrokes = 0

def keyStroke():
    temp = keyboard.read_key()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    global numOfKeyStrokes
    numOfKeyStrokes += 1
    return temp

def init():
    f = open('./DataBase.csv')
    data = csv.reader(f)
    getKeyStroke = []
    matchingFlag = False

    while True: # looping in order to keep getting keystrokes
        global numOfKeyStrokes
        getKeyStroke.append(keyStroke())
        print(getKeyStroke)
        print("numOfKeyStrokes ", numOfKeyStrokes)
        for word in data: # each row is an each cell in a csv file
            matchingFlag = False
            for char in range(numOfKeyStrokes):  # each x is an each letter in an each cell
                print("word[9][char]==getKeyStroke[numOfKeyStrokes-1]", word[9]        [char].lower(),",",getKeyStroke[numOfKeyStrokes-1])
                if word[9][char].lower() == getKeyStroke[numOfKeyStrokes-1]:
                    print("char matched")
                    matchingFlag = True
                    break
                else:
                    matchingFlag = False
                    break
            if matchingFlag == True : print(word[9])

    f.close()

init()
```

Comment: You're only matching a single character to a single character, instead of checking if a word starts with the text so far. Also, please use a standard indent of 4 spaces instead of 1, your code is very hard to read.

Comment: I edited your question to fix the indenting on the code. I don't believe I have made any functional change to the code itself, just changing the indentation. Please check to make sure it is still correct. A friendly suggestion, please indent python using 4 spaces (you were using *one space*)

Comment: I see, thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code only works one time is because you open the csv file once at the beginning of your `init` function.

When you pass it to the `csv.reader` and iterate over the entire file, you consume the resource. When you go for the next iteration the file/reader is empty and so your `for word in data` loop will not run.

I've refactored your program rather significantly, so I don't necessarily know if this still achieves your desired behaviour, especially without knowing exactly how your csv is setup, but I think you were looking for something like:

```py
import csv
import time

import keyboard


def key_stroke_gen():
    num_of_key_strokes = 0
    while True:
        num_of_key_strokes += 1
        yield num_of_key_strokes, keyboard.read_key()
        time.sleep(0.1)


def init():
    get_key_stroke = []
    words = []
    with open('./DataBase.csv') as f:
        data = csv.reader(f)
        for row in data:
            for word in row:
                words.append(word.strip().lower())

    for num_of_key_strokes, key_stroke in key_stroke_gen():
        get_key_stroke.append(key_stroke)
        for word in words:
            if word[:num_of_key_strokes] == ''.join(get_key_stroke):
                print(word)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```

Generating the search_str directly in the generator might be a better approach overall, since it's easier to manage the building of the search string in one place and have the processing code separate.

```py
import csv
import time

import keyboard


def search_strs():
    search_str = ""
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        key_press = keyboard.read_key()
        if key_press == "backspace" and search_str:
            search_str = search_str[:-1]
        elif len(key_press) == 1 and ('a' <= key_press <= 'z'):
            search_str += keyboard.read_key()
        else:
            continue
        yield search_str


def init():
    words = []
    with open('./DataBase.csv') as f:
        data = csv.reader(f)
        for row in data:
            for word in row:
                words.append(word.strip().lower())

    for search_str in search_strs():
        for word in words:
            if word[:len(search_str)] == search_str:
                print(word)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
```